# Persisting Docker state

Tags: ubuntu, docker

I was able to follow [this guide](https://github.com/dockovpn/dockovpn#-quick-start) and run VPN on my Ubuntu 22.04, but was unable to [persist my VPN configuration](https://github.com/dockovpn/dockovpn#persisting-configuration) with

```
-v openvpn_conf:/opt/Dockovpn_data
```

Where should this `/opt/Dockovpn_data` folder appear? At least there is no this folder on the host machine.

`/opt` folder on the host contains the following:

```
me@localhost:/opt$ cd /
me@localhost:/$ ll opt
total 12
drwxr-xr-x  3 root root 4096 Apr 13 15:46 ./
drwxr-xr-x 19 root root 4096 Apr 13 15:46 ../
drwx--x--x  4 root root 4096 Apr 13 15:46 containerd/
```

Should I use `docker commit`?

Answer (score 1):

It is not on the local filesystem, it is a named volume.

`openvpn_conf` is the name of the Docker volume, `/opt/Dockovpn_data` is the path inside the container it will be mounted on.

If you want to use a local directory you need to use a fully qualified path for the first part (and it needs to existing if pre Docker 23)

e.g.

```
-v /opt/Dockovpn_data:/opt/Dockovpn_data
```

This would mount the local `/opt/Dockovpn_data` on `/opt/Dockovpn_data` inside the container (you will need to ensure the permissions are right...)

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#volume